# Spreadsheet_excel_reader date format

Tags: php, excel, date

I'm using spreadsheet_excel_reader to read xls file on php and insert the data into oracle database. I'm using the below code:

```
$filename = 'test.xls';
$reader=new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$reader->setUTFEncoder('iconv');
$reader->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$reader->read($filename);

for($r=1; $r<=$reader->sheets[0]['numRows']; $r++)
{
   for($c=1; $c<=$reader->sheets[0]['numCols']; $c++)
   {
      if (isset($reader->sheets[0]['cells'][$r][$c])) 
      {
         //I'm using this code to get the value
         echo $reader->sheets[0]['cells'][$r][$c];
      }
   }
}
```

My question is, when I try to read the date value, instead of show '01/11/2014', it showing '41944'. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value that you're reading is actually an MS Excel timestamp, typically the number of days since 1st January 1900 (though it could be number of days since 1st January 1904 if the spreadsheet is using the Mac 1904 calendar)

You need to convert this to a Unix Timestamp in order to use PHP date functions with it.... depending on which Calendar is being used, a quick and dirty conversion:

**Windows 1900 Calendar**

```
$unixTimestamp = ($excelTimestamp - 25569) * 86400;
```

and for the reverse

```
$excelTimestamp = ($unixTimestamp / 86400) + 25569;
```

**Mac 1904 Calendar**

```
$unixTimestamp = ($excelTimestamp - 24107) * 86400;
```

and for the reverse

```
$excelTimestamp =  ($unixTimestamp / 86400) + 24107;
```

So MS Excel `41944` => `$unixTimestamp = (41944 - 25569) * 86400;` giving `1414800000` which is the unix timestamp for `1st November 2014`

Once you have a unix timestamp, you can then use PHP's standard date() function or DateTime objects to manipulate and format it as you wish

```
echo date('d-M-Y', $unixTimestamp);
```

Comment: How can I check the value is having date or not using PHP spreadsheet ?