# Convert excel DATEVALUE to javascript date

Tags: javascript, php, excel, date

I am reading excel data using php and JavaScript. Storing results in variable and showing it on the page.

Simple code example:

```
var yearend = "< ? php echo ($connection->sheets[0]["cells"][2][5]); ? >";
```

This works for text and fields with number. But when I format cell as "Date" it returns the values, such as.

Excel field is: `31-Dec-2015` - JavaScript returns value: `40542`

I know it is a MS `DATEVALUE` formatting.

But i need to convert it to date using JavaScript so it shows `31-Dec-2015` or `31 December 2015` only.

So in short:

From Excel `40542` to JavaScript `31 December 2015`.

Also, I only need as above, without trailing time and locations, so removing:

```
00:00:00 00:00 GMT
```

Also is it possible modify the date to +1 day or -1 day?

Comment: datetime::createfromformat and datetime::format, basically. load the excel date string into a DateTime object, then you can format it however you'd like.

Comment: [Quick and dirty formula to convert an MS Excel date/time to a Unix timestamp value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167196/spreadsheet-excel-reader-date-format/28167908#28167908)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Convert Excel dates into JS date objects

//@param excelDate {Number}
//@return {Date}

function getJsDateFromExcel(excelDate) {

 // JavaScript dates can be constructed by passing milliseconds
 // since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970) example: new Date(12312512312);

 // 1. Subtract number of days between Jan 1, 1900 and Jan 1, 1970, plus 1  (Google "excel leap year bug")             
// 2. Convert to milliseconds.

 return new Date((excelDate - (25567 + 1))*86400*1000);

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Above did convert the datevalue to java date, but it is wrong date.

var yearend = new Date(("<?php echo ($connection->sheets[0]["cells"][2][5]); ?>" - (25569 - 1)) * 86400*1000);

returns: Fri Dec 31 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

It should be year 2015 not 2010. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi again, guys,

i have managed to get the date, but now it comes up like Thu Apr 03 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) How do i format it to 3 April 2014?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
toDate(serialDate, time = false) {
    let locale = navigator.language;
    let offset = new Date(0).getTimezoneOffset();
    let date = new Date(0, 0, serialDate, 0, -offset, 0);
    if (time) {
        return serialDate.toLocaleTimeString(locale)
    }
    return serialDate.toLocaleDateString(locale)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following php function to covert the datevalue into a php timestamp. You could then use standard date functions to format however you wish

```
function xl2timestamp($xl_date){
    return ($xl_date - 25569) * 86400;
}
```